# file upload script not working with variables

Tags: php, file-upload, multifile-uploader

I have a PDF uploader that is supposed to save a file to a file path that is based off of a username variable selected from a drop down menu.

Everything works but the uploader, as it displays the usernames and the directories are created upon registration. So there is no issue with that. My issue lies within the code below with the uploader:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="pdf" /><br />
    <select name="folder"> 

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","dbname");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `first_name`, `last_name`, `username` FROM `cw_users` WHERE 1");
$user = 'username';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<option value='". $row["username"] ."'>";
  echo " $row[username] "; 
  echo "</option>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $pdfDirectory = "Users/".$_POST['folder']."/uploaded/";

  //get the name of the file
  $filename = basename( $_FILES['pdf']['name'], ".pdf");

  //remove all characters from the file name other than letters, numbers, hyphens and        underscores
  $filename = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/", "", $filename).".pdf";

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'], $pdfDirectory.$filename)) {
    //the path to the PDF file
    $pdfWithPath = $pdfDirectory.$filename;
  }
}

?>

    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload pdf" name="upload_pdf" />
</form>
```

P.S. if this could be adjusted to upload multiple files at the same time that would be great.

Comment: First this `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` is looking for a submit button named `submit` and yours is `<input type="submit" value="Upload pdf" name="upload_pdf" />` whose name is `upload_pdf`. If anything that should be `if (isset($_POST['upload_pdf'])) {` or rename your submit button like this `<input type="submit" value="Upload pdf" name="submit" />` - Do that and try again.

Comment: thank you yeah that did the trick lol i have been coding for about 48 hours non stop cant believe i missed that.

Comment: You're welcome. I will make it an answer then and you can accept it to mark it as answered. Glad it worked out.

Comment: Otherwise your question will remain in the "unanswered" category.

Comment: In order to have multiple files to be uploaded, have a look at this http://davidwalsh.name/multiple-file-upload which could be useful. You could also look into `Uploadify` http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: funny i was just looking at davidwalsh.name/multiple-file-upload

Comment: I've used it before with success, yet not for DB use though.

Comment: im sure i will get it

Comment: I'm sure you will. The upload part is easy, but for me it's the DB work that I'd have a hard time with.

Comment: lol i am the opposite you think you could help me with the upload part it selects multiple files but only uploads the last one selected

Comment: and if you ever need help with databases let me know

Comment: Thanks. Now for the uploading part; that problem may be caused by the `<select`. It may need to be set to `<select name="folder[]">` or try using checkboxes instead. Have use you used David Walsh's `foreach` example `foreach ($_FILES['uploads']['filesToUpload'] as $file) {` ?

Comment: oh i got that figured out ad yes i a still up lol

Comment: i do have a new issue though will be posting it shortly

Comment: Ok, and as a new question?

Comment: yes it will be a new string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832636/run-different-script-when-check-box-is-checked

Comment: Saw it now. Remember to add `session_start();` (and in your question) since you're using sessions. Plus I noticed a potential typo `documets` in `$sql ="INSERT INTO 'documets'` yet probably won't be able to answer. I think that one's out of my league.

Comment: lol ok then and no that is the table name documets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional statement `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` is looking for a submit button named "submit", yet yours is named "upload_pdf".

```
<input type="submit" value="Upload pdf" name="upload_pdf" />
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That should either read as `if(isset($_POST['upload_pdf']))` or rename your submit button to:

```
<input type="submit" value="Upload pdf" name="submit" />
```